# отключить проверку подлинности сертификата при отправке ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, ssl, https

Добрый день.
Есть АПИ, которая принимает json объект методом post, но доступна она только на https, который, в свою очередь, имеет самоподписанный сертификат.
При попытке отправить запрос - в консоли браузера (Chrome, Opera) пишет:

OPTIONS https://example.com/api net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE.

Вот код ajax'а

```
$.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://example.com/api',

            headers: {
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Accept":"application/json",
                "sid":"777"
            },

            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: $.toJSON(dataToSend),
            beforeSend: befFunc,
            success: sucFunc
        })
```

Есть ли возможность отключить проверку подлинности сертификата при отправке ajax запроса?

Comment: Получите [бесплатный сертификат от Let's Encrypt](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2017/free-ssl-from-letsencrypt/) и проблема решена. Или платный, $5 в год. Всё остальное - костыли.

Comment: так бы и сделал, но ресурс - не мой.

Comment: Сделайте на своем сервере прокси или воспользуйтесь каким-нибудь платным прокси для ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно открыть этот сайт отдельно, добавить сертификат в исключения. Затем все запросы будут у вас работать будто сертификат настоящий.

Если в вашем браузере нет возможности добавить постоянное исключение, то есть способы вообще отключить такие проверки. Например, если запустить хром с этим ключом, то он будет пропускать все проверки:

```
--allow-running-insecure-content
```

Если нужно чтобы не только вы имели доступ к этому сайту, то остаётся только проксировать запросы через свой сервер.

Comment: проблема а в том, что у меня нет сертификата, нечего добавлять. Даже добавил сайт в доверенную зону, все равно запросы не идут.

Comment: Если зайти на тот сайт по https, то вас пускает?

Comment: нет, не пускает, нужно нажимать "Перейти всё равно (небезопасно)"

Comment: Добейтесь того чтобы не нужно было нажимать, и тогда AJAX запросы будут ходить. У хрома был ключик `--allow-running-insecure-content` для этого.

Comment: запустил с ключом, C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-running-insecure-content - тот же результат :(

Comment: Старый выключили перед этим, точно? Попробуйте ещё Firefox, в нём этой проблемы нет. Ещё не закрутили гайки настолько.

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что флаг не тот.

Answer (score 1):

Открой адрес api из адресной строки, нажми продолжить, оттуда залезь в сертификаты и сохрани сертификат, добавь его в доверенные и доверенные корневые. У firefox есть своё хранилище сертификатов, там будет кнопка Add security exception.

Chrome можно запустить с флагами `--disable-web-security` и `--ignore-certificate-errors`.

Comment: Было бы всё так просто уже бы сделал.
Пробовал и с флагами запускать, и в исключения добавлять.
А скачать сертификат нет возможности, его может дать исключительно владелец ресурса.

Comment: _"А скачать сертификат нет возможности, его может дать исключительно владелец ресурса."_ - не может так быть. Сайт предоставляет сертификат при открытии.